# seek() method not working with InputStream available() method in java

Tags: java, file-handling, java-io, seek, randomaccessfile

I am working on this java problem, where I have to write to a text file on the system without tempering existing text data on that file, I am using `randomAceessFile.seek((inputStream.available()+1));` to point my pointer 1 space ahead of existing data, then I have used `randomAceessFile.write((newData.trim()).getBytes());` to write to that file, now the problem is that after this operation file data should have space between existing data and new data that is added, but code below only added new data to file and `\00` instead of spaces in-between data.

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class Random{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("data.txt");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            RandomAccessFile randomAceessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            randomAceessFile.seek((inputStream.available()+1));
            String newData = "new data on file";
            randomAceessFile.write((newData.trim()).getBytes());
            randomAceessFile.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getCause());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The output given by this program is

> existing data
> \00new data on file

Comment: Why are you creating a separate input stream for this? Using `available()` is not the right method, because its return value is not guaranteed to be the length. It would be better to use the `RandomAccessFile.length()`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your suggestion, actually I am new to java so I don't know about it very much

Comment: ' I am using `RandomAccessFile.seek((inputStream.available()+1));` to point my pointer 1 space ahead of existing data': no you aren't. You are using it to point your pointer 1 space ahead of the number of bytes that are available to be read without blocking. What you are doing is a documented misuse of`available()`. It does not return the number of bytes remaining in the stream. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero byte is because you seek to the exiting length plus one. The existing bytes are numbered 0 to length-1, so you want to seek to exactly the existing length.

That is, nothing is specifically written to the file at offset 'existing length', so you get a zero byte.

No-one is going to magically insert a space (0x20 byte) that wasn't there before. You need to do it.  This is easy: `newData = " new data on file"` (and omit the trim call on what you are writing).

Perhaps what you were reading before was using the word 'space' in the sense of 'position' ?

Comment: thanks iggy! for your answer, actually, you are right I am trying to write to file  only by manipulating pointer position but forgot to give space in actual data